# how to switch strings from 14/Nov/2012 into 2012/11/14 without converting to datetime in Python?

Tags: python, string, datetime, logging, converters

Maybe an odd question, but here we go:

I have to parse several log files, which I'm reading in random order. In order to process them sorted I need to sort by the extracted the log-time.

A log entry will look like this:

```
l = 2001:470:1f14:169:5000:eae0:589d:c211 - SOFT12 [14/Nov/2012:09:32:46 +0100] "POST /request HTTP/1.1" 200 984 "-" "-" 181446
```

I can extract the date like this:

```
l.split('+', 1)[0].split('-', 1)[1].split(' ')[2].split('[')[1]
```

which gives me:

```
14/Nov/2012:09:32:46
```

As I'm looking at a years worth of log files with +2million records per day, I don't want to convert anything into a datetime object just so I can switch the format and sort. So I'm looking for a string-only operation that can switch the date-part of the string `14/Nov/2012` into a sortable `2012-11-14`, preferably include-able in my handy split-statement from above...

**Question:**
How do I modify a string-date without converting it into a datetime object?

Comment: Split on slashes, select into a conversion array, concatenate everything back

Comment: considering the complexities of dates and times, I personally would bite the bullet and just do the conversion to DateTime.  When I'm looking at close to a billion records - I really don't want a subtle bug in my string conversion causing an error in 0.01% of the results.  Potential source of subtle bugs: daylight savings time transition in your logs.

Comment: mh. True, but priority is "processing time" right now.

Comment: It sounds like a one-time operation from your question - either way would probably only take a few minutes to run?  But if you are sure that your log timestamps are always from the same timezone and don't have too much funny business with DST, then @lc 's approach is easier and might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @MadKeithV: yup. I'm trying with lc's approach. The single-file script already is optimized for speed and datetime conversion cut 50% of overall processing time, so I will not touch until I really need it

Comment: Side note: you can probably reduce the number of splits you use to get the date, ex. `l.split("+",1)[0].split("[",1)[1]` gives `'14/Nov/2012:09:32:46 '`. That ought to save you a few nanoseconds per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would work:

```
# Converts something like "14/Nov/2012:09:32:46"
# to "2012-11-14:09:32:46"
_MONTHS = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
def convert(s):
  p = s.split(':', 1)
  t = p[0].split('/')
  return "%s-%02d-%02d:" % (t[2], _MONTHS.index(t[1]) + 1, int(t[0])) + p[1]
```

Comment: nice! I don't know how long I would have needed to come up with this... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list and using its `.index()` method, it might be useful to use a dict, because a list would involve a linear search. Even if the list is quite short, the hash operations in a dict MIGHT be faster. At least it is worth trying.

So, taking [Nayuki Minase's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296529/296974):

```
# Converts something like "14/Nov/2012:09:32:46"
# to "2012-11-14:09:32:46"
_MONTHS = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
_MONTHS = dict((m, n + 1) for n, m in enumerate(_MONTHS)) # {"Jan": 1, "Feb: 2, ...} 
def convert(s):
  p = s.split(':', 1)
  t = p[0].split('/')
  return "%s-%02d-%02d:" % (t[2], _MONTHS[t[1]], int(t[0])) + p[1]
```

or even (for saving time)

```
  return "%s-%02d-%s:" % (t[2], _MONTHS[t[1]], t[0]) + p[1]
```

if you can be sure that the day has already the right format (leading 0).

Comment: I have switched from using dict to using lists, which sheds a few ms. Still will give it a try

Comment: Hi glglgl, it would have been nice if you commented on my answer or proposed an edit instead of copying it and making your own answer. Thanks.

Comment: @NayukiMinase Editing would have destroyed your version - which is valid as well. Commenting would have been an option. But as I made clear whose curtesy the code is, I don't see a huge problem...